# What to do with educated guesses in answers

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

This question: [What time format is this guy's "watch"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2143/isnt-something-wrong-with-the-digits-on-this-guys-watch) has an accepted answer that is basically an educated guess as to the format of the time elapsed.

I saw someone down voted it and while they have that privilege, I don't agree with it.
There is absolutely nothing wrong with the answer seeing that is right.

Is it okay to have answers such as these left?

What to do when there is no such citation available? Should I scour the web for citations before answering any question now? Or can I use my knowledge and information from the movie itself to make an educated guess?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've already expressed that I'm perfectly OK with guessing as long as it:

- Makes the OP fully aware that your answer is a guess.
- Is a serious attempt at an answer not a "I guess its X, deal with it"

The nature of this site brings forth *a lot* of speculation and educational guesses so this should be common sense for answers.